# Why is an Identity function needed?

Tags: functions, core-language

Today I came across the function `Identity[x]` in Mathematica ([documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Identity.html)).
The example given in the documentation uses it in `Map` as follows

```
TableForm[Composition[Through, {Identity, Sqrt}] /@ {0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0}].
```

For me, I have always written such maps as

```
TableForm[Composition[Through, {#&, Sqrt}] /@ {0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0}]
```

Is there any real advantage (performance, memory usage, etc ..) for using `Identity` over a lambda function? Are there any examples where one is forced to actually use `Identity`? I am not sure I get the point of having this `Identity` function.

Comment: One good reason for having a built-in, named `Identity` function is that it can be documented in same way as all the other named functions.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are subtle differences between `#&` and `Identity`.

If you pass more than one argument, `Identity` will complain and remain unevaluated, `#&` will just return the first argument.

```
Identity[x, y]
(* Identity::argx: Identity called with 2 arguments; 1 argument is expected. >> *)
(* Identity[x, y] *)

#&[x, y]
(* x *)
```

Also `Identity` is automatically simplified inside `Composition` and `#&` is not.

```
g @* Identity @* f
(* g @* f *)

g @* (#&) @* f
(* g @* (#1&) @* f *)
```

Comment: What does this `@*` construct do? My Mathematica 9 doesn't understand it.

Comment: @Ruslan `@*` is short form for [`Composition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Composition.html).

Comment: @Ruslan. `@*` was introduced in V10